# I keep getting the same error when running python script in Spyder; AttributeError 'GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT'

Tags: python

I keep getting the same error when running my script using the package Salabim:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT'

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in version 21.1.1. Please reinstall salabim with pip.